# yarn install for repositories with git+https not working in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jenkins, npm, yarnpkg

I am trying to configure my project on Jenkins so that each commit will result in an automatic build. 
When I run `yarn install` using Jenkins NodeJS script, it resist to install the the dependencies that are being imported from git repository. I am doing it the following way.

```
"some-component": "git+https://bitbucket.org/owner/repo.git"
```

It shows following error:

```
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: clone git+https://bitbucket.org/owner/repo.git
Output:
fatal: destination path 'some path' already exists and is not an empty directory.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

If the file is empty it show following error

```
error Couldn't find the binary git
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Although the same `yarn install` works perfectly on IDE e.g. VS Code.

I am using the following code to execute `yarn install` in NodeJS Script on Jenkins

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

 child = exec('yarn install ',
 function (error, stdout, stderr) {
     console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
     console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
     if (error !== null) {
          console.log('exec error: ' + error);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

I was receiving the same error while trying to add a package from a git repository while in a docker container.

```
$ yarn add git+https://git@github.com/username/some_repo.git
error Couldn't find the binary git
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

I thought there was an issue with yarn trying to parse the url I used; there are different variations you can use (like https, git+https, ssh).
Come to find out, the docker container I was in, **did not have git installed**.
So when yarn was tasked with trying to retrieve the git repository, it didn't have the git binary to do so.

Solution: **Install git in the docker container**

Hopefully even though the context of my solution is different (I was in a docker container and not in Jenkins job), it might help solve your problem if you ensure that `git` is accessible in your Jenkins job.

You can test this by running `git --version` and there should be a version output proving that you do or don't have git available.

Answer (score 0):

If a package is added through `git+https`, it will be downloaded locally through `git clone` during `yarn install`.

But `git clone <repo-url> <directory>` requires `<directory>` to be a nonexistent directory or an empty directory.

If `yarn install` fails because of `git clone`, it is likely that the package already exists in YARN cache directory, and has files.

One of the solutions is: before `yarn install`, execute `yarn cache clean` to clear the cache.